# Can Tyrus server use inner class endpoints?

Tags: java, websocket, tyrus

I am having a problem getting an extremely simple standalone Tyrus websocket server to work. I have gotten this to work under very specific circumstances that don't make sense to me.

The case that works correctly is where I define a top-level (in its own file) server endpoint class and annotate it with @ServerEndpoint. This class includes methods annotated with @OnOpen, @OnMessage, and @OnClose, all typical stuff. I pass this class to the Server constructor. My simple client can connect to this server, and send it messages successfully that are received by the server.

The problem occurs when I change the top-level server endpoint class to be an inner class of the class that is initializing the server (this is the ONLY change I made). In this case my client can connect and the client's @OnOpen method is called. But the server does not instantiate the server endpoint and, consequently, its @OnOpen method is never called. Obviously, server message receipt does not occur.

Is there a requirement in Tyrus that annotated server endpoint classes can't be inner classes? If not, are there specific permissions on server endpoint classes (everything has been made public attempting to get this to work with no luck)? I'm using Tyrus 1.9 with JDK 1.7 on a Mac, OSX 1.9.5.

The simple server (including and configured to use the inner server endpoint that fails):

```
package tyrus.example;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server;

public class SimpleServer
{
    private static final String HOST_ADDR = "localhost";
    private static final int HOST_PORT = 8025;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server websocketServer = new Server(HOST_ADDR, HOST_PORT, "/ws", null, InnerSimpleServerEndpoint.class);

        try {
            websocketServer.start();
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        websocketServer.stop();

        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

    @ServerEndpoint("/myapp")
    public class InnerSimpleServerEndpoint {
        @OnOpen
        public void onOpen(Session session) {
            System.out.println("Connection received for "+session.getRequestURI());
        }

        @OnMessage
        public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
            System.out.println("Message received: "+message);
        }

        @OnClose
        public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
            System.out.println("Session closed, reason: "+closeReason);
        }
    }
}
```

The simple client:

```
package tyrus.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import javax.websocket.ClientEndpointConfig;
import javax.websocket.Endpoint;
import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig;
import javax.websocket.MessageHandler;
import javax.websocket.Session;

import org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager;

public class SimpleClient
{
    private static final String DEF_WS_URL = "ws://localhost:8025/ws/myapp";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientEndpointConfig cec = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create().build();
        ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();

        try {
            client.connectToServer(new ClientEndpoint(), cec, new URI(DEF_WS_URL));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

    private static class ClientEndpoint extends Endpoint {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
            System.out.println("ClientEndpoint: server session opened: "+session);

            session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(String message) {
                    System.out.println("ClientEndpoint: received message: "+message);
                }
            });

            try {
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello server!");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the non-inner class server endpoint that works when the server uses it:

```
package tyrus.example;

import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/myapp")
public class SimpleServerEndpoint {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connection received for "+session.getRequestURI());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println("Message received: "+message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        System.out.println("Session closed, reason: "+closeReason);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the server, the endpoint can be an inner class, but it also has to be static. Even though the code runs and serves, for some reason, I am only able to make it work if the server endpoint is static as well. Ie: Change to add static in the server code:

`@ServerEndpoint("/myapp")
    public static class InnerSimpleServerEndpoint {
    }`

You may also want to add

`@OnError 
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable throwable) {
      //...
    }`

Comment: Thanks, I got the same problem. the class has to be both public and static.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint can be inner class, BUT it has to be instantiable - class `ClientEndpoint` in your failing example is `private`, thus Tyrus cannot create instance of it.

Change it to public and it should work as expected.

Comment: Pavel the problem is with the server, not the client. Since my client code does the endpoint instantiation, the client works just fine. But the server, as shown above, is using the inner class server endpoint `InnerSimpleServerEndpoint `, which is fully public including constructor, and it fails. Yet when using the standalone class `SimpleServerEndpoint` (also shown above) everything works. What is it about the inner class server endpoint that causes the failure? Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Tyrus?

Comment: Ah, ok, I was too quick to assess this issue. Anyway, in this case, Tyrus does not do anything - the package scanning is delegated to Servlet container - see @HandlesTypes annotation javadoc. I don't see any exclusion of inner classes, so this might be an issue in Servlet impl (or I simply do not read the spec properly). Anyway, you can workaround this by using ServerApplicationConfig class from javax.websocket.server API.

Comment: Thanks Pavel. Is there any example code for using `ServerApplicationConfig` in a standalone application? I did play with this and am getting a null pointer exception (TyrusServerConfiguration.java:191, version 1.10 of tyrus). If you have a link to anything please pass it on.

Comment: sure, for example here: https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/blob/ce57a321c37f132259e2e8acd0b61ca69f88fdca/tests/servlet/autobahn-server/src/test/java/org/glassfish/tyrus/tests/servlet/autobahn/StandaloneServer.java

Answer (score 0):

The inner class should be static otherwise it can not be instantiated without an instance of the outer class. Look at this:
https://www.javatpoint.com/why-we-use-static-class-in-java
So if the the class that is annotated with @ServerEndpoint is not static it can not be instantiated.